pgfplots: filter rows during addplot using row predicate not working
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% Small demo table
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
ID,x,y
Exp1,0.1,10
Exp1,0.2,20
Exp2,0.1,5
Exp2,0.2,10
}\experimentdata


  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
      % Plot data for Experiment 1 using row predicate to filter
      \addplot+[
        table/x=x,
        table/y=y,
        table/row predicate/.code={%
          \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{ID}\of\experimentdata
          \edef\temp{\pgfplotsretval} % Get value from "Experiment" column
          % Only plot if the experiment is "Exp1"
          \ifx\temp{Exp1}
            \pgfmathparse{1} % Include this row
          \else
            \pgfmathparse{0} % Skip this row
          \fi
          \pgfmathresult > 0
        }
      ]
      table {\experimentdata};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

I am trying to use table/row predicate/.code insde addplot to plot independently the rows associated with ID's Exp1and Exp2.
The above code does not work and it seems that the block inside table/row predicate/.code is not even entered: The code compiles even if I write something like \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{BLABLABLA}\of\experimentdata.
What is going wrong here?

From the pgfplots documentation p.501 to filter rows in addplot.
\pgfplotsset{
  only if/.style args={entry of #1 is #2}{
    x filter/.code={
      \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
      \edef\tempb{#2}
      \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \else
        \def\pgfmathresult{}
      \fi
    }
  }
}

to filter rows in \pgfplotstabletypeset
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
  columns={x,y},
  row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{#1}\of{experimentdata.dat}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{#2}}
      {}
      {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}
  }]
  {experimentdata.dat}

Complet code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

% from the pgfplots documentation p.501
\pgfplotsset{
  only if/.style args={entry of #1 is #2}{
    x filter/.code={
      \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
      \edef\tempb{#2}
      \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \else
        \def\pgfmathresult{}
      \fi
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myExp}{m m}{
  \centering
{\bfseries Table for #2 #1:}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
  columns={x,y},
  row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{#1}\of{experimentdata.dat}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{#2}}
      {}
      {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}
  }]
  {experimentdata.dat}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    table/col sep=comma
    ]
    \addplot table[x=x,y=y,only if={entry of #1 is #2}]{experimentdata.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{experimentdata.dat}
  ID,x,y
  Exp1,0.1,10
  Exp1,0.2,20
  Exp2,0.1,5
  Exp2,0.2,10
\end{filecontents*}

\myExp{ID}{Exp1}

\myExp{ID}{Exp2}

\end{document}


